# What is the proper way of using a Image variable in regards to tkinter, pillow, python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am currently using StringVar for changing text in labels while application is running. I am now trying to use a similar approach for images so that when I change images in my application, the old one is not left behind and new one placed in front of it. I have been searching tutorials online and have not found anything. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
class Book():
    def __init__(self, title_var, author_var, price_var, image_var):
        self.title_var = title_var
        self.author_var = author_var
        self.price_var = price_var
        self.image_var = image_var
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title_var
    def get_author(self):
        return self.author_var
    def get_price(self):
        return self.price_var
    def get_image(self):
        return self.image_var
    def set_title(self,title_var):
        self.title_var = title_var
    def set_author(self,author_var):
        self.author_var = author_var
    def set_price(self,price_var):
        self.price_var = price_var
    def set_image(self,image_var):
        self.image_var = image_var
root = Tk()
root.title('Book Database')
root.geometry("+600+100")
root.iconbitmap('Book_Databases_Icon.ico')
book_var_001 = Book("Title: Homeland",
                    "Author: R.A. Salvatore",
                    "Price: $1.98",
                    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("large_homeland.png")))
book_var_002 = Book("Title: Exile",
                    "Author: R.A. Salvatore",
                    "Price: $2.98",
                    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("exile_rasalvatore2.png")))
book_var_003 = Book("Title: Sojurn",
                    "Author: R.A. Salvatore",
                    "Price: $3.98",
                    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("sojurn_rasalvatore2.png")))
book_var_004 = Book("Title: The Crystal Shard",
                    "Author: R.A. Salvatore",
                    "Price: $4.98",
                    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("thecrystalshard_rasalvatore2.png")))
book_var_005 = Book("Title: Streams of Silver",
                    "Author: R.A. Salvatore",
                    "Price: $5.98",
                    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("streamsofsilver_rasalvatore2.png")))
book_list = [book_var_001, book_var_002, book_var_003, book_var_004, book_var_005]
image_list = [book_var_001.get_image(), book_var_002.get_image(),
              book_var_003.get_image(), book_var_004.get_image(),
              book_var_005.get_image()]
output_string_price = StringVar(value=book_list[0].get_price())
output_string_title = StringVar(value=book_list[0].get_title())
output_string_author = StringVar(value=book_list[0].get_author())
image_label = Label(image=book_list[0].get_image())
image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
price_label = Label(textvariable=output_string_price,
                    font=("Ariel", 22), bd=1)
price_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
title_label = Label(textvariable=output_string_title,
                    font=("Ariel", 22), bd=1)
title_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
author_label = Label(textvariable=output_string_author,
                     font=("Ariel", 22), bd=1)
author_label.grid(row=1, column=2)
def forward(image_number):
    global image_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back
    image_label = Label(image=book_list[image_number-1].get_image())
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    output_string_price.set(str(book_list[image_number - 1].get_price()))
    output_string_title.set(str(book_list[image_number - 1].get_title()))
    output_string_author.set(str(book_list[image_number - 1].get_author()))
    button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1),font=("Ariel", 22))
    button_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: back(image_number-1),font=("Ariel", 22))
    if image_number == 5:
        button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", state=DISABLED,font=("Ariel", 22))
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    button_back.grid(row=2,column=0)
    button_forward.grid(row=2, column=2)
def back(image_number):
    global image_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back
    image_label = Label(image=book_list[image_number - 1].get_image())
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    output_string_price.set(book_list[image_number - 1].get_price())
    output_string_title.set(book_list[image_number - 1].get_title())
    output_string_author.set(book_list[image_number - 1].get_author())
    button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1),font=("Ariel", 22))
    button_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: back(image_number-1),font=("Ariel", 22))
    if image_number == 1:
        button_back = Button(root, text="<<", state=DISABLED,font=("Ariel", 22))
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    button_back.grid(row=2,column=0)
    button_forward.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_back = Button(root,
                     text="<<",
                     command=back,
                     font=("Ariel",
                           22))
button_exit = Button(root,
                     text="Exit Program",
                     command=root.quit,
                     font=("Ariel",
                           22))
button_forward = Button(root,
                        text=">>",
                        command=lambda: forward(2),
                        font=("Ariel", 22))
button_back.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_exit.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_forward.grid(row=2, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried running the application above, and it works but does not replace old image with new image. It just places new image on top of old image. The same thing was happening before I started using StringVar. Thankfully I was able to fix that issue.

Comment: Before you Label a new image you have to remove the previous label. If my memory serves me well it is something like image_label.destroy(). image_label is each time created locally and does not need to be global. StringVar is a different object where you can set/ update the text variable.

Comment: I tried deleting the image before and had no luck with that method. Perhaps I was just not doing it properly. I will try that again.

Comment: When I try to clear image in function before assigning new image, it throws an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image_label' referenced before assignment